# WPF ItemsControl data binding with variable path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a UserControl that contains an ItemsControl which should display Parameters and their values. The values must be editable and these values should be transferred back to the ViewModel.

It should be possible to define which property represents the parameter name and which property the parameter value.

Parameter class:

```cs
public class Parameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

UserControl ("ParameterList.xaml"):

```xml
<UserControl x:Name="ParameterList" ...>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="100">
        <!-- I don't know if this binding expression is correct -->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:ParameterList}}, Path=Parameters}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <!-- The property path defined via "ParameterNameMember" should be bound. -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ???}" />

                    <!-- The property path defined via "ParameterValueMember" should be bound. -->
                    <!-- The value edited in this TextBox should be transferred to the ViewModel. -->
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding ???}" />
                </Border>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl code behind:

```cs
public partial class ParameterList : UserControl
{
    public IEnumerable Parameters
    {
        get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ParametersProperty);
        set => SetValue(ParametersProperty, value);
    }

    public string ParameterNameMember
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ParameterNameMemberProperty);
        set => SetValue(ParameterNameMemberProperty, value);
    }

    public string ParameterValueMember
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ParameterValueMemberProperty);
        set => SetValue(ParameterValueMemberProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParametersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Parameters", typeof(object),
            typeof(ParameterList), new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParameterNameMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ParameterNameMember", typeof(string),
            typeof(ParameterList), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParameterValueMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ParameterValueMember", typeof(string),
            typeof(ParameterList), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public ParameterList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I want to use the control as follows:

```xml
<uc:ParameterList
    x:Name="ParameterList"
    Parameters="{Binding Parameters}"
    ParameterNameMember="Name"
    ParameterValueMember="Value" />
```

Since I don't have that much experience with WPF, I need some help with the data binding. I would be very grateful if I could get some useful suggestions.

Comment: Name and Value inplace of ??? if rest of your bindings are correct

Comment: the problem is Parameter is not bindable in your code. you can inherit it from DependencyObject and define Name and Value as DP so that they reflect any change from UI.

Comment: Also I don't see any reason to define Parameters twice (one in VM one in UC). IMO you must delete the UC code behind completely and only bind to the VM. having an extra layer of data achieves nothing.

Comment: @Bizhan How can I define which property should be used as name and which as value if I don't have these information in my code behind file? Any class should be bindable to my user control.

Comment: @AthulRaj The property names must be variable (see title of this post)

Comment: sorry I misread your post. I think the only way to do it as you described is by reflection which is slow and ugly because you need to write the binding in code. another way is to use generic type for UC and pass the type of the parameter to it, and forget about sending name of "Name" and "Value" members and use an interface for them in all the view models instead. I would prefer the third option which is converting the data into a common VM with fixed names.

Comment: And if you just Bind to {Binding} and do the rest with a IValueConverter?

Comment: @Klamsi Unfortunately I do not know exactly what you mean. I don't have that much experience with WPF yet. Do you think you could provide an example?

Comment: @Felix: You will have to generate the `ItemTemplate` programmatically based on the values of your parameters. There is no way to inject dynamic binding paths into a `DataTemplate` using XAML markup.